# Magento2.2.4 : What is The New Features in New Release Magento (2.2.4)?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4

- What is the **difference** between Magento 2.2.3 and **2.2.4** version?
- Is the Main thing of New Release Reduces Cart Abandonment in Magento 2.2.4?
- What are the new features were introduced in these release?
- What is the difference when we move from 2.2.3 to 2.2.4

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.4CE.html

Answer (score 3):

1 ) **What is the difference between Magento 2.2.3 and 2.2.4 version?**

- Functionality wise there is a huge difference between both few
  functionalities which is newly adapted by magento and also there are
  couple of bugs which fixed in 2.2.4 version

2 & 3) **Is the Main thing of New Release Reduces Cart Abandonment in Magento
   2.2.4? AND What are the new features were introduced in these release?**

- AKAIK main thing should be like Magento has introduced few new features in these release notes Below i have listed for the same.
- **Amazon Pay**
- **Vertex**
- **Klarna Payments**
- **Including that in this version magento has fixed more than 50+ minor bugs along with improvement in performance optimization**

Here is the release notes link for Magento version 2.2.4 - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.4CE.html

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2.1.4 contains more than 20 functional fixes and enhancements, and one security enhancement.

Here are the full details of the new version **2.2.4**

Check [magento 2.1.4 Release Notes](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.4CE.html):

It will definitely help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please read a release notes firstly and you will find all the answers you need. We are not going to write everything that has changed btw those two versions, that would be ridiculous.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.4CE.html

Answer (score 0):

**What is the difference between Magento 2.2.3 and 2.2.4 version?**

Major different is added new features listed down in next questions below and lot of bug fixes and new enhancements.

for more info  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.4CE.html

---

**What are the new features were introduced in these release?**

In the payment side two payment added Amazon pay and Klarna Payments.

1) **Amazon Pay** :  provides a trusted, familiar way for customers to check in and check out. See Amazon pay for a full description of the advantages this solution offers merchants and their customers

2) **Klarna Payments** : merchants can provide customers with the option to pay now, pay later, or pay by installment for their purchases

---

In Tax 
 **Vertex** : simplifies and automates the complexity of calculating sales tax

for more info vertex tax http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/tax/vertex.html

---

**Dotmailer :** Merchants can now use dotmailer to create their own transactional email templates.

Other feature added

- Support for custom transnational email templates
- Transactional email can now be set at store level
- Validation for CSV files deleted during cron jobs
- Abandoned Cart report

---

**Magento Shipping**

- **New carrier added: WnDirect**
- FedEx pre-negotiated rates
- Ad-hoc returns support for shipments sent by FedEx, USPS, Australia Post, UK Mail, and DHL Express
- Integration with Magento Order Management
- Basic Reporting
- Improved interface for Shipping Experience Rules

---

Reference : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.4EE.html